# code is ignoring WhenEvent

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I would like the value of `x[t]` to be equal to 0 when it has a negative value so I used `WhenEvent` but it has no effect on my code why?

The code:

```
Clear[ss]; 
a = 0.5;
u = 7;
v = 4;
years = 365;
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == a*x[t - u]*(1 - x[t - v]), 
x[t /; t <= 0] == 0.8, WhenEvent[x[t] < 0, x[t] -> 0]},x, {t, 0, 365}];
ss = Table[Flatten[{t, Evaluate[x[t] /. s]}], {t, 0, 365}];
Clear[s]
ListLinePlot[ss, PlotRange -> All]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`WhenEvent` is working. Try `WhenEvent[x[t] < 0, Print[t]; x[t] -> 0]` to see that every crossing is detected.  The problem is that it only detects **crossings**. So changing `x[t] -> 0` does not reset the event. At the next step `x[t]` becomes negative and no event is detected.  (This is how it is supposed to behave.)

The way to deal with this is to use [`DiscreteVariables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteVariables.html).  Perhaps this is what you desire:

```
Clear[x, ss];
a = 0.5;
u = 7;
v = 4;
years = 365;
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == stop[t]*a*x[t - u]*(1 - x[t - v]), 
    x[t /; t <= 0] == 0.8, stop[t /; t <= 0] == 1, 
    WhenEvent[x[t] < 0, stop[t] -> 0]}, x, {t, 0, 365}, 
   DiscreteVariables -> {stop}];
ss = Table[Flatten[{t, Evaluate[x[t] /. s]}], {t, 0, 365}];
Clear[s]
ListLinePlot[ss, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Another stab at what is desired:

```
clip[f_] := Piecewise[{{f, f > 0}}];
s2 = First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == a * clip@x[t - u] * (1 - clip@x[t - v]),
     x[t /; t <= 0] == 0.8},
    {x}, {t, 0, 365}];

Plot[Evaluate[clip@x[t] /. s2], {t, 0, 365}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note the desired solution is `clip@x[t]`, not `x[t]`.

Comment: I gave an answer based on my first impression of what you were asking.  It was based on "it was to be zero when it was negative," which is perhaps not really possible: if a value is negative, it cannot also be zero :).  Once it's zero, `x` cannot become positive. But maybe I misunderstood. Perhaps you want `x` to become positive when the history makes `x'[t] > 0`?

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate it. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @N-A You're welcome.